# PHP Date Convert

Tags: php, datetime

Whats the problem in that code that output the wrong date?

```
$date = "1990-05-07"; // Y-m-d
$date1 = date("d/m/Y", strtotime($date)); // Here is fine.
$date2 = date("Y-m-d", strtotime($date1)); // Here is wrong.

echo $date2; // output: 1990-07-05
```

---

**The code above is a simple demonstration, the exactly code is:** (Yii Framework)

Model.php

```
public function afterFind()
{
    if ($this->birthday)
    {
        $this->birthday = date("d/m/Y", strtotime($this->birthday));
    }
}

public function beforeSave()
{
    if ($this->birthday)
    {
        $this->birthday = date("Y-m-d", strtotime($this->birthday));
    }
}
```

Comment: Its output is correct.....its outputting 190-07-05.wat is your problem?

Comment: @VikasUmrao The input is month 05, day 07. His final output is month 07, day 05.

Comment: Please do not put the solution into the question. Add it as "your" answer below so it's kept for reference. `strtotime` btw. is for guessing, you don't need any guess here, you just need to parse from a known format, see [`date_parse_from_format`](http://php.net/date_parse_from_format).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solution Using 'Vikas Umrao' TIP:**

```
public function afterFind()
{
    if ($this->birthday)
    {
        $birthday = explode("-", $this->birthday);
        $mktime = mktime(0,0,0,$birthday[1],$birthday[2],$birthday[0]);
        $this->birthday = date("d/m/Y",$mktime);
    }
}

public function beforeSave()
{
    if ($this->birthday)
    {
        $birthday = explode("/", $this->birthday);
        $mktime = mktime(0,0,0,$birthday[1],$birthday[0],$birthday[2]);
        $this->birthday = date("Y-m-d",$mktime);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Because you're changing `$date` from "1990-05-07" to "07/05/1990". You've changed it from `Y-m-d` to `d/m/Y`, and the parser is recognizing this as `m/d/Y`. You *cannot* reuse the resule of the first date call, as it will not parse the way you think it will.

### Solution 1 (best)

Reuse the timestamp you parsed from the original date, and you will not mess up the original timestamp:

```
$date = "1990-05-07"; // Y-m-d
$timestamp = strtotime($date);
$date1 = date("d/m/Y", $timestamp);
$date2 = date("Y-m-d", $timestamp);
echo $date1 . " ; " . $date2;
```

### Solution 2 (also good)

Do as [@PragneshChauhan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1307530/pragnesh-chauhan) said, as he beat me to editing my post.

### Solution 3 (less-than-ideal)

Reset `$date` between the calls to `date()`, and it works fine:

```
$date = "1990-05-07"; // Y-m-d
$date = date("d/m/Y", strtotime($date));
echo $date; // output: 07/05/1990

echo "\n";

$date = "1990-05-07"; // Y-m-d
$date = date("Y-m-d", strtotime($date));
echo $date; // output: 1990-05-07
```

Proof of concept: http://codepad.org/JnVpDFb7

Comment: Without reseting how can I make the code working? Because I coded it as a demonstration, Im using the first code on my afterFind model and the second in beforeSave, so I cannot reset it.

Comment: Assign the result of each `date()` call to a new variable instead of reusing `$date`.

Comment: That not fixed the problem. I edited the first post.

Comment: ... no, no. You're again reusing the `$date1` variable, which it is parsing as `m/d/Y`. You *cannot* reuse these variables like this.

Comment: Thats any way to parse to strotime the date structure?

Comment: Yes, PHP has a default parsing mode, and when you pass it `07/05/1990`, it reads it as "month 7, day 5, year 1990", ***not*** as "month 5, day 7", like you want.

Comment: the problem is the date2 is not always date1. It comes from a form and may have changed, and they are used in 2 different functions in a Model.

Comment: Check the first post, I edited it so you can understand better whats happening.

Comment: Okay, you're basically going to use solution 1 in my edited post. *Only save the timestamp*; that is, `$this->birthday` should *always* be a numeric value. Then, when you need to display it, have a function `->getBirthday($format)`, and return `date($format, $this->birthday)`. You can also use [`date_parse_from_format`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date-parse-from-format.php) (5.3.0+) to parse from any format, including `d/m/Y`.

Answer (score 0):

try

```
$date = "1990-05-07"; // Y-m-d
$date1 = date("d/m/Y", strtotime($date));
$date2 = date("Y-m-d", strtotime($date));
echo $date2; // output: 1990-07-05
```

Answer (score 0):

You Can also use it like this:

```
<?php
  $date = "1990-05-07"; // Y-m-d
  $date_ex=explode("-",$date);
  $date1=mktime(0,0,0,$date_ex[1],$date_ex[2],$date_ex[0]);

  $date=date("d/m/Y",$date1);
  $date=date("Y-m-d",$date1);

//echo $date = date("d/m/Y", strtotime($date)); // Here is fine.
//echo $date = date("Y-m-d", strtotime($date)); // Here is wrong.

echo $date; // output: 1990-07-05
  ?>
```

Comment: I cannot use it as I coded that simple code only as demonstration. I use them in separated functions in my Model.

Comment: now replace your code $date = "1990-05-07"; // Y-m-d with $date = "1990-05-07"; // Y-m-d
  $date_ex=explode("-",$date);
  $date1=mktime(0,0,0,$date_ex[1],$date_ex[2],$date_ex[0]); and in your variables replace strtotime($date) with $date1

Comment: Yeah that is a valid alternative, but I would like to know if there is any way to parse the date structure to strotime.

Comment: Then on top Eric have suggested the answer

Comment: I did a solution using your tip and worked well.

Comment: great........what you have done?